# Yii: Rendering A View inside CKEditor Text Area

Tags: yii, ckeditor, yii-extensions

Yii Newbie here,
I was wondering if there was anyway to render a view which I have previously made inside a CKEditor TextArea.

I tried rendering it inside the value attribute, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Is there any way to do this? or should I create a seperate function and output the page into the text area?

Any tips, advices or pointers are greatly appreciated !! Thank You

```
          <?php
    $this->widget('application.extension.CKEditor.TheCKEditorWidget', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'body', 
         'value' => //rendered page,    
        'height' => '400px',
        'width' => '800px',
        'toolbarSet' => 'Full',
        'ckeditor' => Yii::app()->basePath . '/../ckeditor/ckeditor.php',
        'ckBasePath' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/ckeditor/',
        'css' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/css/index.css',
    )); ?>
```

Comment: see this post http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9341-ckeditor-widget-in-a-cactiveform/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` attribute is not used if you specify `model` and `attribute` attributes. So inorder to display a something inside CKeditor you must specify it as `$model->body="Your content goes here"` before rendering the widget. In your case you have to render a view inside CKEditor. So use `CController::render()` function with third parameter as true. ie

```
<?php
    $model->body=$this->render("viewName",array(),true);

    $this->widget('application.extension.CKEditor.TheCKEditorWidget', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'body',  
        'height' => '400px',
        'width' => '800px',
        'toolbarSet' => 'Full',
        'ckeditor' => Yii::app()->basePath . '/../ckeditor/ckeditor.php',
        'ckBasePath' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/ckeditor/',
        'css' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/css/index.css',
    )); ?>
```